# Drag rigid body based on touch in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics, rigid-bodies

I want to drag object based on Player touch and drag in device. So for reference I have used following script:

[nucleartide/DragPiece2D.cs](https://gist.github.com/nucleartide/7638121)

At present object was not reacting based on touch. But definitely joint between two objects get established.

You can check following two images for more understanding.

- Joint created and I dragged mouse

[image]

- Rigidbody Dragger Inspector

[image]

Actual object not getting any response of drag, so I want to move object based on drag.

Comment: In your inspector screenshot, I don't see the linked script being attached to the game object in question.

Comment: This is dragger object's inspector so that one created runtime by script. Plugin script I have attached to Cube object.

Comment: Now I have implemented following things and able to reach at this point http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/physics-implementation-for-dragging-and-joint.422251/